# Phonegap override Go key on the soft-keyboard

Tags: cordova, overriding, android-softkeyboard

i am trying to trigger a click event on a button whenever user presses 'Go' on android soft-keyboard. any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<div class="combined_input ui-shadow-inset">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" value="" data-mini="true"   class="bb_1">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" value="" data-mini="true">
</div>

<div data-role="none" class="login">
    <input type="button" value="Login" class="ok" id="login-btn" data-mini="true">
</div>
<div data-role="none" class="cancel">
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancel" onClick="exitApp()" data-mini="true">
</div>
```

when user enters password and presses 'Go' button, i would like to trigger a click event on `login-btn`. can that be done?

Regards,

JadeSync.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#password').on('keyup', function(e) {
                var theEvent = e || window.event;
                var keyPressed = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
                if (keyPressed == 13) {
                    $('#login-btn').trigger( 'click' );
                }
                return true;
            });
        });
```